# Troubles with suftesi and itemize

Tags: sectioning, lists

A while ago I was experimenting with `suftesi` and chapters of my thesis, adapting the preamble that had been created using the standard class `book` and it works. I want to try the layout of sufitesi, but I have an strange problem.

When I compile and add each chapter, suddenly I've got an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@enditemize ->\enit@after 
                           \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \ifnu...
l.13 \end{itemize}
```

It seems that the problem has to do with the itemize environment, something very strange, because with the class `book` I have not problems. I want to highlight that I read before the documentation of `suftesi` class and from there was I used my preamble options. I have not seen any trouble with itemize.

A MWE then should be:

```
\documentclass[documentstructure=book,pagelayout=standard,tocstyle=ragged,headerstyle=center,captionstyle=standard, parindent=wide,style=sufelements]{suftesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amstext,amssymb}

\usepackage{multicol,multirow,array,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[cbgreek]{bpchem}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%output-decimal-marker = {,},
detect-weight= true, 
range-units = brackets,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,etex,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Objetivos}

\section{Objetivo general}

\noindent Sintetizar óxidos binarios basados en mezclas de Ir y Ru mediante una síntesis coloidal como electrocatalizadores para la reacción de evolución de oxígeno \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} (REO) en un electrolizador tipo \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} ESP que superen las propiedades electrocatalíticas de los óxidos simples \BPChem{IrO\_2} y \BPChem{RuO\_2}, es decir, que reduzcan el sobrepotencial requerido para la \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} REO mejorando su cinética lenta. 

\section{Objetivos específicos}

\begin{itemize}
\item Caracterizar físicamente los materiales sintetizados mediante difracción de rayos X \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} (XRD), microscopia de barrido electrónico (SEM), área superficial por la técnica de \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} BET para determinar la morfología y tamaño de partícula de los óxidos binarios en estudio.
\item Evaluar la actividad electrocatalítica de los materiales sintetizados a través de su caracterización electroquímica con técnicas como voltamperometría cíclica \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} (VC), \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} lineal (VL) y cronoamperometría \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} (CA).
\item Evaluar los materiales en un electrolizador tipo \todo[color=cyan]{acrónimo} ESP. Realizar la comparación del desempeño de la serie de óxidos binarios con un óxido comercial \BPChem{IrO\_2}. 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Well the MWE works, but with the whole document (all the chapters) not. I'm using TeXLive 2013 updated. I made a proof in [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52ae71dcbce66e9e2a0027cb?r=adddd2c8&rs=ps&rm=d) and it works but with errors. I don't understand what's wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: It's difficult for a doctor to diagnose a problem if the patient sends his healty brother to the visit. It's irrelevant, but you shouldn't be loading `ucs`.

Comment: That's the reason why I uploaded the sick brother in sharelatex. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: ShareLaTeX is based on an old TeX Live (2011). It's surely possible that something that works on TeX Live 2013 doesn't on an outdated release.

Comment: Ok, but well there is the whole code for proofs. BTW in ShareLaTeX there are issues also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `paralist` that is incompatible with `enumitem`. Since `suftesi` relies on `enumitem`, you have to remove the call to `paralist`.

Comment: Well it seems that the problem was in fact the `paralist` package. I removed it from the premable, erased the auxiliar files and complied again. And there are not errors. I added chapter by chapter and all works. Thanks.